# Duplicate title tags and meta descriptions in Google Webmaster Tools from removed blog

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content, fetch-as-google

I added a blog on my website like this:

`www.example.com/blog`

Then I created a page just like this:

`www.example.com/blog/contact`

Also, I added this link to '**Fetch as Google**' in Google Webmaster Tools.

After one month, I just removed this blog from my site, but unfortunately I received the following errors from Google Webmaster Tools' HTML Improvements:

- Pages with duplicate title tags
- Duplicate meta descriptions

Both errors are coming from my blog, how can I correct these errors?

[image: Resp.Image]

Comment: Can you tell us how you know these errors are coming from the blog you removed?

Comment: @dan  Links are listed in Pages with duplicate title tags

/blog/category/wordpress/
/blog/find-callers-from-unknown-numbers/
/blog/tag/frameworks/
/blog/tag/theme/

Comment: It is important to know that Google Search Console (webmaster tools) is often days or weeks behind on some things. It may be nothing about nothing in the end.

Comment: @closetnoc  i removed this blog around 3 months before, still the same errors

Comment: @ShanuTThankachan Just to be clear here, those pages are no longer accessible, and a [410 status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) is received when they're requested? If not, you should fix that.

Comment: @dan  How to Setup HTTP 410 Error Pages with .htaccess

Comment: @ShanuTThankachan Please use our Search function above to find [similar questions](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=htaccess+410+is%3Aquestion). Since it seems by your comment that these URLs weren't returning the proper status code, this question is being closed.